# Custom section{}

Tags: sectioning, customize

I'm fairly new to LaTeX, but I still try to customize my LaTeX experience as far as possible (otherwise, I'd use a simple WYSIWYG software lol!). But I get a little bit confuse by some commands.
I was trying to customize my section{}, and found this neat code :

```
\RequirePackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{color}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\definecolor{seccol}{rgb}{0,0.8,0.3} % This is a kind of greenish color... you can define the exact color you want here!
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\bfseries}{
\fontsize{100}{100}\selectfont\color{seccol}\thesection}{0pt}{\linebreak\huge\raggedleft}[{\titlerule[0.5pt]}]
```

[On this site](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1510)

Here is how it looks :
[image: How the original code looks]

I really like it, but I wanted to modify it.

First things first :
Could someone please break down this code for me :

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\bfseries}{
\fontsize{100}{100}\selectfont\color{seccol}\thesection}{0pt}{\linebreak\huge\raggedleft}[{\titlerule[0.5pt]}]
```

?

Because to be able to modify it, I think I must first know what it does precisely. But I can't find any good and simple documentations online.

Here's how I would like to modify it :

- I want the chapter number to be on the right (as it already is) ;
- But I want the chapter name to be on the left ;
- I don't want the chapter to be raggedleft. I want it to be justify (or flushleft if not possible) ;
- I want the chapter name to take the whole line (or to be able to decide how much of the line it takes) ;
- I don't want any indent for the chapter name.

Thanks !

Here is my entire code, just in case :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,portrait,hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin={2.5cm,2.1cm},headheight=12.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\RequirePackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{color}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{seccol}{rgb}{0,0.8,0.3} % This is a kind of greenish color... you can define the exact color you want here!
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\bfseries}{
\fontsize{100}{100}\selectfont\color{seccol}\thesection}{0pt}{\linebreak\huge\raggedleft}[{\titlerule[0.5pt]}]
\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\section{This is an example of how a section would look with these commands : I really like it but I'd like to change a few things}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are using `titlesec` package, you will have the manual on your system ( `texdoc titlesec` ) or online at https://texdoc.org/serve/titlesec/0

Comment: Your question is totally ok, I've no idea why somebody voted it down. It's a kind of bad habit here.

Comment: @KeksDose Thanks. It's okay.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, I've looked at it, but it does not seem like I can customize it the way I want.

Comment: don't you just want to remove the `\raggedleft` you added, so you get the default unindented, justified paragraph layout?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right! It was really as simple as that...
I'm a newbie, thanks for helping.

How to avoid hyphenation in titles?
I used this commend : \hyphenpenalty=10000. Do you know any alternatives you'd advise?

Comment: I'd use `\raggedright`, justified text without hyphenation is just awful, but then I don't think I've ever used a section title long enough to need automatic line breaking. But I've only been using latex 37 years, perhaps the need will come up  one day.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My section titles for this document are really long.
37 years! Impressive.